# Setar valor existente no combo box C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Estou passando um objeto DTO preenchido para um formulário de edição, através do evento click em um button Alterar.

Nesse formulário de edição, quero que todos os campos sejam preenchidos assim que ele for aberto, porem os campos que são combo box não estão sendo preenchidos os demais sim.

```
private void btnAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dto.Id = (int)DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        dto.Descricao = DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dto.Valor = Convert.ToDouble(DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);

        dto.CategoriaReceita = (int)DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
        dto.DescCategoria = DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

        dto.Conta = (int)DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;
        dto.DescConta = DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

        dto.DataVencimento = (DateTime)DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value;
        dto.Observacao = DgvCadListReceita.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();

        FrmCadReceita frm = new FrmCadReceita(dto);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        CarregarGrid();
    }
```

No formulário que recebe o objeto DTO preenchido

```
 public FrmCadReceita(ReceitaDTO dto)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtDescricaoReceita.Text = dto.Descricao;
        txtValorReceita.Text = Convert.ToString(dto.Valor);

        cboCategoriaReceita.Text = dto.DescCategoria.ToString();
        cboConta.Text = dto.DescConta;

        dtpDataVencimentoReceita.Text = dto.DataVencimento.ToString();
        txtObservacaoReceita.Text = dto.Observacao;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como faço pra que o combobox inicie com o valor da descrição que esta no objeto DTO? neste caso estou passando o valor do tipo string, mas tenho o DTO idCategoria preenchido também

Answer (score 1):

Os campos não estavam sendo carregado devido a não inicialização do combo, criei um procedimento para carregar o combo, em seguida, chamei ele em uma condição dentro do evento Load

```
private void CarregarCombos()
    {
        cboCategoriaReceita.DataSource = catBll.Exibir();
        cboCategoriaReceita.DisplayMember = "des_categoria_receita";
        cboCategoriaReceita.ValueMember = "id";

        cboConta.DataSource = contBll.Exibir();
        cboConta.DisplayMember = "desc_conta";
        cboConta.ValueMember = "id";
    }

private void FrmCadReceita_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dto != null)
        {
            txtDescricaoReceita.Text = dto.Descricao;
            txtValorReceita.Text = Convert.ToString(dto.Valor);

            CarregarCombos();
            cboCategoriaReceita.SelectedValue = dto.CategoriaReceita;
            cboConta.SelectedValue = dto.Conta;

            dtpDataVencimentoReceita.Text = dto.DataVencimento.ToString();
            txtObservacaoReceita.Text = dto.Observacao;
        }
        else
        {
            LimparCampos();
        }
    }
```